# Oracle Dynamically create script for Updating Partitioned table

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, sql-update

I have a range partitioned Oracle table which I want to update using partition key.

Is there a way to dynamically create update script which takes into account partition key as follows, WITHOUT having to manually maintain such script

```
  update table where date between 'a' and 'b'

  update table where date between 'b' and 'c'.
```

Comment: What is the partition key for that table? If it's the `DATE` column (which btw. is a horrible name for a column) then Oracle will automatically take care of only updating rows in the corresponding partitions.

Comment: Are you talking about updating data in the table, or updating the table partitioning definition?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : table colum = invoice_date. The table has over 300 million rows. We cannot update all of them at once. Hence we are trying to update one partition at a time by specifying INVOICE_DATE between 'Jan 01 2018' and 'Jan 31 2018'

Comment: @MarkStewart - updating a table. It has over 300 million rows.

Comment: So what is the partition key?

Comment: Partition Key is INVOICE_DATE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would not be necessary to specify the range in the `where clause` to update individual partitions. You may use the  [partition_extension_clause of update](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10008.htm#i2130226) dynamically.

```
BEGIN
     FOR r IN (
          SELECT partition_name
          FROM user_tab_partitions
          WHERE table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE'
     ) LOOP

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE YOUR_TABLE (' || r.partition_name || ')  SET somecol = somevalue where someother_clause';

      COMMIT; --if it's necessary
     END LOOP;
END;
/
```